# Open game in game app

Tags: javascript, android, html, phaser-framework

I need open game in game...

What i mean :
Open the app: 
[Pandachii](http://nwstudio.esy.es/panda/)

Now go to 4th button (game pad).
And when we click on game icon i want to open the game (this game below pandachii window ( brick destryer) ).
I also need to get point from this brick destroyer to pandachii.

Pandachii game is on file : js/main.js - 
http://nwstudio.esy.es/panda/js/main.js

Brick Destroyer is on file : js/brick-destroy.js

Also when we open this game brick-destroyer the pandachii must be running in background (still alive).

This game will be emulated to android app with some framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a rather broad question to which there could be many answers; it comes down to an architectural decision based on the framework you choose to use and what you mean exactly by

> pandachii must be running in background

I am going to work on the assumption that you must be able to communicate with pandachii, e.g. brick-destroyer must be able to query pandachii for certain information as well as send certain information back to pandachii; and also that once you finish with brick-destroyer you wish to return to pandachii at the same state you left from. I will summarize three possible approached below: fragments, a game framework developed by Mario Zechner, and WebView.

**Fragments**

My current preferred solution to this type of problem is to use fragments. I use a main activity with a container into which I can swap different fragments at need. Each [fragment](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html) performs a particular function (this would be your game) and manages its own state. In order to be able to communicate with pandachii, you will need to keep a handle on the fragment for pandachii even when it is not displayed.

To communicate between fragments I use the Fragment to Activity communication mechanism described at Communicating with Other Fragments. The main activity is registered as a listener for a callback from the fragment (such as one for brick-destroyer). To pass the message on to another fragment (such as one for pandachii), the main activity uses findFragmentById() to locate the fragment for pandachii and then call the appropriate methods in that fragment.

To switch between fragments (games) you handle some event in your current fragment (game) (corresponding to clicking the game icon in your question above) that triggers communication to the main activity (see preceding paragraph), where you can use a FragmentTransaction to switch the displayed fragment - a process also described at Communicating with Other Fragments.

There are a couple of wrinkles to this approach. First, you want pandachii to be running in the background so you must keep a reference to the fragment for pandachii in your main activity (alternately if you actually want it displayed at all times then load that fragment into a second container in your main activity; this means you will need to handle the fragment for your subordinate game such as brick-destroyer a little differently). Second, if there is code that must actually be executing in pandachii while you are running brick-destroyer, then a Thread inside the pandachii fragment appears to be the obvious answer.

For running javascript directly with this approach, read the WebView section.

**Mario Zechner's Framework**

Mario Zechner described a game framework he developed in **Beginning Android Games** (ISBN 978-1-4302-3042-7). The book (or at least my copy) was published in 2011 so it is a little dated - it makes no use Fragments for example. But the framework is still solid.

In essence, Zechner uses a single activity with a canvas into which each game will render. A game is implemented by a series of classes, such as a Screen class that performs rendering directly into the main activity's canvas, and a World class that maintains the state of the game. The main activity swaps between Screen instances at need - in Zechner's framework there is a single game screen with other screens used for setting options, displaying high scores, and so forth. But the framework is adaptable to handle the case of multiple games.

In this framework as well you will retain a reference to the Screen/World objects representing pandachii in your main activity, and communicate through calls on the main activity.

For running javascript directly with this approach, read the WebView section.

**WebView**

Without naming the framework, you say:

> This game will be emulated to android app with some framework.

From your tags I infer that you would like to use the Phaser HTML5 framework. That might make Zechner's framework more suitable conceptually to your needs since his framework is already working with canvases.

However, you could use WebView directly. [Building Web Apps in WebView](https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html) describes how to bind your javascript code to Android code, which can provide a mechanism for inter-game communication. In this case you might have to build proxy objects for your javascript games; for example an object to store or reconstruct the state of pandachii when you start brick-destroyer. Alternately, you might use two WebViews, one always displaying pandachii (but with visibility set to GONE when you are running a subordinate game) and the other displaying the subordinate game (with visibility set to GONE when no subordinate game is played); then you use the javascript to Android binding to communicate between the two WebViews.

This use of WebView could be combined with either of the other two approaches mentioned above. In the Fragment-based approach place a WebView in the Fragment and run the javascript in the Fragment. Bind the Fragment code to the javascript and continue using the inter-Fragment communication methods described above. In Zechner's framework, replace the canvas in the main activity with a container into which you place a WebView managed by the Screen class (and each Screen gets its own WebView); again bind the Screen code to the javascript code and use that to communicate between games.